# Testing whether one interval overlaps other intervals

Tags: functional-programming, typescript, interval

I recently started to learn functional programming and wan't to know If I'm doing things right.

I use `@effect-ts/core` lib as well as `date-fns` to check if interval overlaps other intervals

```
import * as Arr from '@effect-ts/core/Collections/Immutable/Array'
import * as B from '@effect-ts/core/Boolean'
import { pipe } from '@effect-ts/core/Function'

const isIntervalOverlapsOtherIntervals = (
  interval: Interval, // { start: 11:00, end: 12:00 }
  otherIntervals: Interval[] // [{ start: 09:00, end: 10:00 }, { start: 11:00, end: 13:00 }]
): boolean =>
  pipe(
    otherIntervals,
    Arr.forAny((otherInterval) =>
      pipe(
        isWithinInterval(interval.start, otherInterval),
        B.or(isWithinInterval(interval.end, otherInterval))
      )
    )
  );
```

I want to know if this function is readable enough or some improvements can be added? I want to use `pipe` approach to write functions as well as best practices of FP